# Preventing @ from printing ARRAY in this class

Tags: php, wordpress

This one has me beat...

I have this wordpress class that basically scans posts & comments for mentions and outputs the content depending on what it finds.

Wherever it finds '@somename' in the post content it strips the @ symbol and searches the WP db to see 'somename' is a valid user.

If user exists it returns the original '@somename' hyperlinked to their user account.

If user doesn't exist it just returns the original '@somename' without a link.

This is working perfectly but the problem I'm having is that if it finds '@ somename' with a space it returns 'Array'.

Same thing if it finds 'somename@' or any other combination of symbols around the @ symbol "@", #@, '@', @$ or pretty much anything else you can think of.

I guess what I'm asking is how to only apply the routine if it finds correctly formatted "mentions" - ie - @somename (with no spaces or any other characters other than a-z and 0-9 around it.

Here is the class :

```
 Class d3ep_stream_mentions {

function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( __CLASS__, 'link_user_mentions' ) );
    add_filter( 'comment_text', array( __CLASS__, 'link_user_mentions' ) );
}

//Strip @ from string preparing for callback
public static function link_user_mentions( $content ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $content;
    }
    return preg_replace_callback( '/@[0-9a-zA-Z]*/', array( __CLASS__, 'content_callback' ), $content );
}

//Callback function that filters potential authors
public static function content_callback( $mention ) {

    $split_a = str_replace( '@', '', $mention );
    if ( !isset( $split_a[0] ) || empty( $split_a[0] ) )

        return $mention;

    // Check if the user exists
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', esc_attr( $split_a[0] ) );
    if ( empty( $user ) || !isset( $user->user_login ) || empty( $user->user_login ) ){

        return '@'.esc_attr( $split_a[0] ).'';
    }

    // Return the link              
    return '<span class="stream-mention">@</span><a href="'.site_url().'/user/' .$user->user_login.'" class="stream-mention" rel="friend" target="_parent">' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '</a>';
    }
}
new d3ep_stream_mentions();
```

I know it can be achieved by wording the preg_replace_callback differently but I just don't know what that should be. I'm guessing strpos needs to be used in there somewhere too.

I've tried several things, none of which worked so I'm hoping the gods of SO can save me here ;)

Comment: Have you tried just changing the regexp.   think you want `'/@[0-9a-zA-Z]+/'` not `'/@[0-9a-zA-Z]*/'` - `*` is zero-or-more - you want + which is one-or-more letters after the `@`

Comment: @Adam You sir are a legend! Thank you so, so much :)

Comment: @Grant If you got the answer as you mentioned above, please post it here and accept your own answer. Don't keep the question open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as derived from Adam's post was to change the regex :

```
return preg_replace_callback( '/@[0-9a-zA-Z]+/', array( __CLASS__, 'content_callback' ), $content );
```